# jenkins job not triggering commands and performing ui validations in the targeted machine

Tags: java, jenkins, command, ui-automation

I configured a job for doing GUIAutomation(**which got developed using java code including running commands and keyboard events**) in the targeted machine.

*Extra Info:-*

1. I am running a command to launch the **installer**(installer **GUI** should come).....but its not happening
2. When I got any error I am capturing a image using **JAVA DefaultToolkit API**, but very time its coming as *Black*, nothing there to watch.
3. GUIAutomation tool was developed by myself.

Please help me to overcome this problem, since I have to automate it through jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, problems running GUI programs in Jenkins occur because of the Jenkins service not having privileges to access the display of the slave (or master, you don't mention which) that is running the job. A typical solution is to start the slave via JNLP, which requires logging on to the slave, navigating to the slave's page on the jenkins master (via browser on the slave) and launching the slave process via the button on that page. You can also launch using the javaws command which will be shown on the same page.

[image: Starting a JNLP slave]

On Windows slaves running as a service, you may have success by configuring the service to run as a user with login and desktop privileges for the slave - the default is the Local System user which has no such rights.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same job as you.

1. You have to create the jnlp connection. I create one batch file in slave machine such as: jar -jar slave.jar -jnlpurl  (your url)/slave-agent.jnlp
2. If it's remote slave, it's better to use VNC instead of remote desktop when you operate that machine. Because when you close the session, remote desktop will hold the session, so the screenshot would be black.